# Homeowner's Insurance - Didn't Make Deductible - Must I Make the Repairs?

Tags: united-states, home-insurance

After a big hail storm dented our aluminum gutters, we filed a claim with our homeowner insurance company.  Our deductible is $2000, and the insurance company assessed the damage at $1900.  As a result, of course, we received no money for the filed claim.

Even though we did not receive any money from the insurance company, are we still expected to repair the gutters?

My gut tells me that the answer is yes, but it just seems funny...

Comment: I'd advise against making claims for small repairs.  If the repair was for 2100, the 100 from the insurer would not offset potential increases in premium or being dropped by the company.

Comment: To add to what @PeteB. said, this will show up now any time you want to get any kind of insurance. Story time, we had a few feet of flooding in basement, called agent who said that "standard homeowners insurance doesn't cover once water hits the ground". Total call length of less than five minutes, no specifics discussed, no claim made, no paperwork, etc. When we bought a new home in another state, the insurance scan came up with a claim for flood damage that we then had to explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to make the repairs, if they're just cosmetic. The insurance company doesn't care if your house looks good or not.

On the other hand, if the repairs are structurally necessary to prevent water damage to the house, not making them may result in the company raising your rate or not renewing the policy due to the increased risk. You can try asking your agent if you can get a ruling on that now, before deciding whether to spend the money.

And of course if you don't do it, they may not count this damage toward your deductible for future damage this year.

Comment: expanding on the 3rd paragraph. You have reported the damage. If you report another incident in the future that covers the same area of the house, they may want proof of the repair or they will determine that the new damage is actually the old damage and not cover it.